# How to Develop individual dashboard interface for different users

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

Hello fellow developers,

I am at an intermediate level in Backend Development using Django. I need to create a dashboard system whereby different users can create an account which automatically creates a Bar for them on which they can view their individual analytics on it.

I am not sure of what specific keyword to use to search for my request, but I think it's somewhat close to a multivendor system.

I would be glad to have recommendations as to how to get this done or references to simple systems similar to this or tutorials.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like [metabase](https://www.metabase.com/). it is open source and very powerful. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: can I use it in my Django project and how easy is it please because I need to integrate just that feature in my current Django project.

Comment: It is a java based project, and you don't java to run it. You can use their docker image, and it will be a lick away from running it. You like the project from the Django project, and it will save you a lot of headaches. Else you have to code the whole thing yourself. It would be very interesting to find a solution of a similar scale which is offered by Metabase, Powerbi, etc. If you find something kindly leave it in the comments here.